# Local Listener in Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I learn Oracle Databases and have some question:

If i have 1 default listener:

```
LOCAL LISTENER, (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=1521))
```

Is it possible to connect to my database from:

> 1. Local Network (172.X.X.X)
> 2. Virtual Machines (192.168.X.X)
> 3. VPN (10.X.X.X)

I talk about default system network settings, without port's forwarding e.t.c.

**I understand, that Local means Local, but** may be it's OK for Oracle to accept traffic from "trusted" sources. It's often practice in services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOCAL_LISTENER parameter simply tells the database where to contact the listener for dynamic registration ... so that the listener will know about the database without it having to be configured in the SID_LIST section of listener.ora.  Once the listener knows about the database - whether through dynamic registration (via LOCAL_LISTENER) or static registration (via SID_LIST in listener.ora), it doesn't matter *how* it came to know about it.  If the listener receives a valid request, it will attempt to service it.

BTW, if the listener is running with all default values, particularly the default port of 1521, you can leave LOCAL_LISTENER as null.  The default values for dynamic registration mesh perfectly with the default values of the listener.